# Credit card payments and notifications on the Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

I ported gchecky to the google app engine. you can [try it here](http://web2py.appspot.com/plugin_checkout)

It implements both level 1 (cart submission) and level 2 (notifications from google checkout).

Is there any other payment option that works on the google app engine (paypal for example) and supports level 2 (notifications)?

Comment: http://web2py.appspot.com/plugin_checkout says "invalid request" nowadays.